# HSSFCell setCellStyle apply style on all sheet's cell instead the selected cell

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssf

I transform a string called sCurrentLine to an Excel's row. Depending if the line is starting with X, Y or Z I color the row.

```
        row = sheet.createRow(lines);
        String[] parts = sCurrentLine.split("\\|");

        if (sCurrentLine.contains("X")) {
            bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.RED.index;
        } else if (sCurrentLine.contains("Y")){
            bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE.index;
        } else if (sCurrentLine.contains("Z")) {
            bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.YELLOW.index;
        } else {
            bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.BROWN.index;
        }
```

So I am having this variable called bgColorIndex and use it to set the color of all the cells of the row

```
        for (short i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            row.createCell(i).setCellValue(parts[i]);

            HSSFCell curCell = row.getCell(i);
            HSSFCellStyle curStyle = curCell.getCellStyle();
            curStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            curStyle.setFillForegroundColor(bgColorIndex);
            curStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(bgColorIndex);
            System.out.println("Color is: " + bgColorIndex);

            curCell.setCellStyle(curStyle);
        }
        lines++;
    }
```

The issue I am having is setCellStyle is applying the style for all the rows and sheets, so the last color I detect is applied to whole document.

How can I color independently every cell?

EDITED:
Whole code:

```
private void generateCSVFile() {
    String filename = "excel.xls" ;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");  

    HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);

    // header
    rowhead.createCell((short)0).setCellValue("AXIS");
    rowhead.createCell((short)1).setCellValue("INIT");
    rowhead.createCell((short)2).setCellValue("MID");
    rowhead.createCell((short)3).setCellValue("END");     

    // Set columns width
    for (short i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
        sheet.setColumnWidth(i, (short)(20*300));
    }

    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {

        fr = new FileReader("data.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        short lines = 1;
        HSSFRow row = null;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (sCurrentLine.contains("AXIS")) {
                lines = 0;
                sheet = workbook.createSheet("SecondSheet");  
                // Set columns width
                for (short i = 0; i < 7; i++)  {
                    sheet.setColumnWidth(i, (short)(20*256));
                }

                row = sheet.createRow(lines);
            } 

            row = sheet.createRow(lines);
            String[] parts = sCurrentLine.split("\\|");

            short bgColorIndex = 0;
            // Check the first cell to set color for X, Y or Z
            if (sCurrentLine.contains("X")) {
                bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.RED.index;
            } else if (sCurrentLine.contains("Y")){
                bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE.index;
            } else if (sCurrentLine.contains("Z")) {
                bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.YELLOW.index;
            } else {
                bgColorIndex = HSSFColor.BROWN.index;
            }

            for (short i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

                row.createCell(i).setCellValue(parts[i]);

                HSSFCell curCell = row.getCell(i);
                HSSFCellStyle curStyle = curCell.getCellStyle();
                curStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                curStyle.setFillForegroundColor(bgColorIndex);
                curStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(bgColorIndex);
                System.out.println("Color is: " + bgColorIndex);

                curCell.setCellStyle(curStyle);
                curStyle = null;
            }
            lines++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if (br != null)
                br.close();

            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole block of code? It seems that you are first finding the colors, hence remembering the last one, and then setting it to the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create four different CellStyle in the workbook:

```
CellStyle styleX = wb.createCellStyle();
styleX.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
styleX.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
styleX.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
CellStyle styleY = wb.createCellStyle();
styleY.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
styleY.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE.index);
styleY.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE.index);
CellStyle styleZ = wb.createCellStyle();
styleZ.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
styleZ.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
styleZ.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
CellStyle styleOther = wb.createCellStyle();
styleOther .setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
styleOther .setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BROWN.index);
styleOther .setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.BROWN.index);
```

And, for each row:

```
CellStyle style = null;
row = sheet.createRow(lines);
String[] parts = sCurrentLine.split("\\|");

if (sCurrentLine.contains("X")) {
    style = styleX;
} else if (sCurrentLine.contains("Y")){
    style = styleY;
} else if (sCurrentLine.contains("Z")) {
    style = styleZ;
} else {
    style = styleOther;
}
for (short i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    row.createCell(i).setCellValue(parts[i]);
    HSSFCell curCell = row.getCell(i);
    currCell.setCellStyle(style);
}
```